# SFTP and SCP file transfers stalled

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, raspbian, scp

I'm having trouble doing a SCP transfer from a RaspberryPi running Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy) to a DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

The two machines are connected via a StrongSwan VPN. There is a firewall running on the ubuntu machine, however I have double checked and there is nothing that should have any effect on the transfer of files. I can transfer files in via SCP and SFTP remotely over the Internet as well using the same credentials.

The verbose output of `scp` is below:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.16.0.5 ([10.16.0.5]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /var/sftp/snapshots/scp.png
Sending file modes: C0644 3057 snapshot.png
Sink: C0644 3057 snapshot.png
snapshot.png                                                                         100% 3057     3.0KB/s   00:00
```

As you can see, it looks like the file transfers 100%. The file is actually created on the remote computer, however it has a zero file size. The transfer never seems to complete.

Answer (score 1):

It was a firewall issue on my router. As the router is connected to the server I'm trying to copy to by an IPSEC VPN, there were fragmentation issues (I think) from incorrect MTU sizes.

```
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
```

I found the fix [here](https://www.zeitgeist.se/2013/11/26/mtu-woes-in-ipsec-tunnels-how-to-fix/).